# <textarea> is breaking the page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to Insert infusionsoft contact form code in a CodeBlock of Avada theme.

But there is a textarea in form with following code

```
<div class="infusion-field">

    <label for="inf_custom_Comments">Message *</label>

    <textarea cols="24" id="inf_custom_Comments" name="inf_custom_Comments" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

This field is causing problems. It breaks the page and all the code of page including footer code is displayed in textarea as text. Below is screenshot

http://oi68.tinypic.com/2mn166a.jpg

I have Viewed the page source and here is what it look likes :

```
<div class="infusion-field">

    <label for="inf_custom_Comments">Message *</label>

    <textarea cols="24" id="inf_custom_Comments" name="inf_custom_Comments" rows="5">

&lt;/textarea></div>
```

Now this is showing that textarea is not getting closed properly. How to fix this issue ?

The of form is working on some pages of website and causing problem on other pages.

Comment: Do u use normal WG editor or any other editor.?

Comment: </textarea> type it manually or copy and paste from here

Comment: remove javascripts or css if any on that element and check

Answer (score 0):

You must be using some type of wysiwyg editor which is converting your html angular brackets into unicode characters. please use plain html editor to fix this issue.